# I am using cursor to fetch rows from a temp table but else if condtion is not working, is this a good approch to do these type of task on MSSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a temp table having record id, module id and status id, now i have to check every row of that temp table and according to @levelid i have to update corresponding table with that status id,
but below code never goes to else if condition, i am new to mssql seeking for your valuable answers :)

```
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR; 
DECLARE @LevleId INT, 
        @STATUS  VARCHAR(max), 
        @RECID   VARCHAR(max); 

BEGIN 
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR 
    FOR SELECT TOP 1000 level_id, 
                        status_id, 
                        record_id 
        FROM   #temp_record_id_typ2 
        WHERE  approval_typ_id = 2 

    OPEN @MyCursor 

    FETCH next FROM @MyCursor INTO @LevleId, @STATUS, @RECID 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
      BEGIN 
          IF ( @LevleId = 1 
               AND @STATUS != 3 ) 
            BEGIN 
                SELECT @Update_Typ2_Rec = N'UPDATE hrms_approvals  SET approval_status_id = ' +
                       @STATUS 
                         + ' WHERE record_id = ' + @RECID 
                         + ' AND module_id = ' + @Module_id + 
                       ' '; 

                --SELECT @Update_Typ2_Rec 
                EXECUTE Sp_executesql 
                  @Update_Typ2_Rec; 

                SELECT @UPDATE_MODULE_TABLE = N'UPDATE ' + @TableName + 
                                              '  SET approval_status_id = 9  WHERE id = ' 
                                              + @RECID + ''; 

                --SELECT @UPDATE_MODULE_TABLE 
                EXECUTE Sp_executesql 
                  @UPDATE_MODULE_TABLE; 

                PRINT 'LevleId = 1' 
            END 
          ELSE IF ( @LevleId = 2 
               AND @STATUS != 3 ) 
            BEGIN 
                SELECT @Update_Typ2_Rec = 
                       N'UPDATE hrms_approvals  SET approval_status_id = ' 
                       + @STATUS + ' WHERE record_id = ' 
                       + @RECID + ' AND module_id = ' 
                       + @Module_id + ' '; 

                --SELECT @Update_Typ2_Rec 
                EXECUTE Sp_executesql 
                  @Update_Typ2_Rec; 

                SELECT 
            @UPDATE_MODULE_TABLE = N'UPDATE ' + @TableName 
                                   + '  SET approval_status_id = 10  WHERE id = ' + @RECID + ''; 

                --SELECT @UPDATE_MODULE_TABLE 
                EXECUTE Sp_executesql 
                  @UPDATE_MODULE_TABLE; 

                PRINT 'LevleId = 2' 
            END 
          ELSE IF ( @LevleId = 3 
               AND @STATUS != 3 ) 
            BEGIN 
                SELECT @STATUS, 
                       @LevleId 

                PRINT 'LevleId = 3' 
            END 
          ELSE IF ( @LevleId = 4 
               AND @STATUS != 3 ) 
            BEGIN 
                SELECT @STATUS, 
                       @LevleId 

                PRINT 'LevleId = 4' 
            END 
          ELSE IF ( @LevleId = 5 
               AND @STATUS != 3 ) 
            BEGIN 
                SELECT @STATUS, 
                       @LevleId 

                PRINT 'LevleId = 5' 
            END 

          FETCH next FROM @MyCursor INTO @LevleId, @STATUS, @RECID 
      END; 

    CLOSE @MyCursor; 

    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor; 
END;
```

Comment: What are you *really* trying to achieve here? At least 99% of the time (and that isn't a made up figure, I really mean 99%+) whenever I see someone using a `CURSOR` or a `WHILE` (and you're using both!) they're not doing it right; SQL Server excels at Set based methods not iterative ones and a `CURSOR` and `WHILE` are iterative. You also have some big injection issues in your code here, as you're not quoting your objects or parametrising the parameters in your Dynamic statements. This whole query needs to be put in the shredder or incinerator and completely rewritten I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok @Larnu I am new to SQL

Comment: I am trying to make check that depends upon level id and and status id in my temp table

Comment: I think you would be far better off providing sample datam expected results and describing (well) your expected behaviour. We can then show you how to do what you want the right way; as what you have at the moment is very much the wrong way I'm afraid; for so many reasons.

Comment: thanks @Larnu i am not going to use this code :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code,You didn't declare this Parameters "**@TableName** and **@ModuleId**", Check your code and assign the value for @TableName and @ModuleId

```
Declare @Counter int=1
        ,@Tot_Count int=0
        ,@LevleId int 
        ,@Status int
        ,@RecId int
        ,@Module_id int
        ,@TableName varchar(30)=''

Create Table #Temp_Table
(
    Id int identity(1,1)
    ,level_id int
    ,status_id int
    ,record_id int
    ,Module_id int
)

Insert into #Temp_Table
(
    level_id,status_id,record_id
)
 Select level_id
        ,status_id
        ,record_id 
        ,Module_id
   from #temp_record_id_typ2
  where approval_typ_id = 2 

Select @Tot_Count=Count(1) from #Temp_Table

While @Tot_Count >= @Counter
Begin

         Select @LevleId=level_id 
                ,@Status=status_id
                ,@RecId=record_id
                ,@Module_id=Module_id
           from #Temp_Table
          where Id=@Counter

          IF ( @LevleId = 1 AND @STATUS <> 3 ) 
            BEGIN 

                Exec
                ('
                     UPDATE hrms_approvals  
                        SET approval_status_id = ' + @STATUS + ' 
                      WHERE record_id = ' + @RECID + ' 
                        AND module_id = ' + @Module_id +' 

                     UPDATE '+ @TableName +'  
                        SET approval_status_id = 9  
                      WHERE id = '+ @RECID + '
                ') 

                PRINT 'LevleId = 1' 
            END
            ELSE IF ( @LevleId = 3 AND @STATUS <> 3 ) 
            BEGIN 
                    SELECT  @STATUS, 
                            @LevleId 

                    PRINT 'LevleId = 3' 
            END 
            ELSE IF ( @LevleId = 4 AND @STATUS <> 3 ) 
            BEGIN 
                    SELECT @STATUS, 
                           @LevleId 

                    PRINT 'LevleId = 4' 
            END 
            ELSE IF ( @LevleId = 5 AND @STATUS <> 3 ) 
            BEGIN 
                    SELECT @STATUS, 
                           @LevleId 

                    PRINT 'LevleId = 5' 
            END 

         Set @Counter+=1

End

Drop table #Temp_Table
```